# Can I host a high traffic website at home?

Tags: web-hosting, performance, isp

I've been searching this up on google but I can't formulate my google search with the right terms to find an accurate answer to my question.

Is it possible to have a super-fast connection at home to host a high traffic website? What is the generic term for that kind of connection? What's the major drawback of hosting at home? (I have no idea of the price range but it's probably quite expensive)

Do you have to be a company to have the right to own such a connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bonded T1, DS1, SDSL (Symmetric DSL) Check with your Local Exchange Carrier to see what their offerings are.
Business Cable 20-100Mbit down/3-5Mbit up

It's usually against the TOS to use asymmetrical home use Internet Access like ASDL and Cable. Two of the main reasons are:

a)while the downlink has blazing speed, the uplink speed (control traffic outbound) is a small fraction of the downlink speed (you sitting there receiving web content for your own consumption). Since your major traffic on a website is outbound, your blazing speed is not so much so if you're running 8Mbit down/1Mbit up, your webserver traffic is limited to 1Mbit minus your personal needs.

b)the uplink channel can be on shared resources, so any one person hogging the uplink causes traffic degradation for all and this often is a major reason why hosting a public web server or ftp download server is prohibited in the TOS.

So, usually, the best way is to just face facts and go get a VPS (Virtual Private Server) which often has 100Mbit internet access without even asking. It costs a lot less than bringing in a high speed internet connection and paying the monthly fee for it.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not a good idea to host a business site (much less a high traffic one) on a regular residential broadband (or even most business broadband) connections, it is possible in some places to get a residential T3/DS3 connection, which is about 43~45Mbps.

However, the problem with trying to host business sites from home is the availability of such high speed connections in residential areas. Usually, unless you live right on the border of an industrial district or commercial district, you simply won't have access to such high speed connections as they require dedicated lines (either a T3 coaxial cable or a DS3-level fibre optic line), and it's simply not economical for ISPs to lay down cables to residential areas where there's no demand for such industrial-grade connections.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Interesting fact about proximity with industrial districts. Regards